# How to create and read .txt file with fs.writeFile to AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

​Hello,

Does someone know how I can write a .txt to AWS Lambda? I'm using Node.js, Alexa Skills Kit and Lambda.

My code:

```
var fs = require('fs');


const handlers = {
    'SetOrderIntent': function() {
       if (this.event.request.intent) {
            var test = this.event.request.intent.slots.Items.value;
            fs.writeFile('/tmp/log.txt', test, function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
            });
            this.emit(':ask', 'This is your item: ' + test, "Test");
        }
    },
    'RetrieveOrderIntent': function() {
       if (this.event.request.intent) {
            fs.readFile('/tmp/log.txt', function (err, content) {
                if (err) return callback(err)
                callback(null, content)
            })
            this.emit(':ask', content);
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

thing is, that your `/tmp` folder is only guaranteed to be persistent during the execution of your lambda function. So; if `SetOrderIntent` is called and executed in one lambda call and `RetrieveOrderIntent` in another lambda call, these are two separate lambda executions and it is not guaranteed that `/tmp` is still available.

To make sure the data you saved in one lambda execution is still there when the read function is called, you should store your data on S3 or so.

Comment: Would you recommend me using S3 or to use session.Attributes?

Comment: I think it depends on the size of your data but for me it looks like its only a string right? Than you should try session.Attributes. 

Also, you are emitting sync in `RetrieveOrderIntent`. that means your emit is fired before readFile actually finishes in the callback. your should move `this.emit` inside the readFile callback. Also where does `callback` come from?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure it out, so what I did was select the "New File" option inside the Alexa Dev Cons and after that call it through a function so Alexa could read it

[new file---> test.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjJUN.png)

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUZvp.png)

[textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dybuy.png)

It's important that you give the type file in the end so the lambda function could read it

Then the code goes this way

```
class HelloWorldIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):

def leer_archivo(self):
    contenido = "empty"
    with open("./prueba.txt", 'r') as archivo:
        contenido = archivo.read()
    return contenido

"""Handler for Hello World Intent."""
def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
    return ask_utils.is_intent_name("HelloWorldIntent")(handler_input)

def handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
    speak_output = self.leer_archivo() #"Hello World!"
    return (
        handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speak_output)
            .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
            .response
    )
```

I hope it helps